# Is there any function / API to customize a slicer width in Google Sheet with Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to customize a slicer width through Apps Script but i can't see any function or API calls to do this.
According to the documentation, I can customize many things but the slicer width is not a part of it.

Any help appreciated.

Alex

Comment: Perhaps provide you script so we can see what you have tried so far?  And what is "slicer width"?

Comment: I want to custom slicer width for layout reason. I use Sheets that are automaticly updated with data, and the problem is that the slicer range is not updated according to the number of rows. So I need to delete them and recreate them through Apps Script every time new data is added. I retreive all slicer metadata and put it again (because I cannot modify slicer range only)

Comment: Please provide your script and an example.  I have no idea what a "slice width" is.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.